# How can I make my Content View Window became borderless in SwiftUI for macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nsview, nswindow

I am using this code for making my Window became borderless, but all I am getting is crash in run time!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("borderless") {
            NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.styleMask = .borderless
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

---

From Xcode Help:

@note The styleMask can only be set on macOS 10.6 and later. Valid \c styleMask settings have the same restrictions as the \c styleMask passed to `-initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:`.  Some \c styleMask changes will cause the view hierarchy to be rebuilt, since there is a different subclass for the top level view of a borderless window than for the top level view of a titled window.

*Xcode version Version 14.1 (14B47b)*

The goal is solving the error that using the code does not crash the app and not changing the question.

Answer (score 1):

A window that uses `NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless` can’t become `key` or `main`, which is why your code doesn't work.

What you could do however is to hide each element of the titlebar instead:

```swift
if let window = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow {
    window.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
    window.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
    window.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
    window.titleVisibility = .hidden
    window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
}
```

---

This assumes you only want to change main window. If you want to change all windows, you should loop all windows instead.

Comment: This almost solve the result but after using your answer the window has steal cornered edges which I just need a window with rectangular shape like the one we get it with `styleMask = .borderless`